# Why do the Japanese sing Ode to Joy during the Japanese New Year?

Tags: japan, cultural-history, social-history, music

During the New Years days, the Japanese have a curious custom where they perform Beethoven's 9th symphony. This has produced some stunning sights on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBlQZyTF_LY)

But there's nothing particularly festive or New Year like with this music. How did this tradition come about?

Comment: In reality the tradition you quote is quite rare these days. I would say almost nobody hears. Or more to say, it was around 30 years ago when I heard Beethoven's 9th symphony was performed in New Years.

Comment: And I am afraid to say, almost 99% people in here know such a history by Semaphore. I doubt how many know Japan was in allied side in the WW1, and I bet 97% people wouldn't know we fought with Germans in WW1.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This modern tradition has its roots in the [First World War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I), when Japan entered on the side of the [Allies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allies_of_World_War_I) following the [Anglo-Japanese Alliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Japanese_Alliance).

Japan's entry carried an initial, overt goal of restoring the German [Kiautschou Bay Concession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiautschou_Bay_concession) to Chinese sovereignty. The [Siege of Tsingtao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Tsingtao), the administrative centre of the German concession, ended in the surrender of the German garrison. The 4,700 prisoners of war were then transferred back to Japan and until the end of the war, in generally good conditions.

The Germans were eventually consolidated at Banto, Tokushima, on the island of Shikoku. To pass the time during the war years, the German camps set up various activities, comforting themselves with sports but also cultural events. Each camp organised performances of classical German music - including [Beethoven's Symphony No. 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._9_%28Beethoven%29).

They entertained fellow German prisoners, but eventually also the Japanese locals.

> On 1 June 1918, while the First World War still raged in Europe, the small town of Bando on the island of Shikoku witnessed an extraordinary event. German prisoners of war in the nearby camp staged the first full performance of Beethoven's Ninth Symphony on Japanese soil. According to the programme, this was the second symphonic concert by the Tokushima Orchestra and it was assisted by a choir of 80 men and four soloists under the baton of Herman Hansense, a military band master.
>
> **<sub>- Mehl, Margaret. *Not By Love Alone: The Violin in Japan, 1850-2010.* The Sound Book Press, 2014.</sub>**

Many Germans had begun working in Japanese society, where they were reportedly paid fair wages. Thus by the time the Germans were repatriated in 1920 and 1921, strong ties to the local community had been established. The Germans and their performances as well as cultural exchanges left its mark on Japanese society.

> After the prisoners were repatriated, the people of Tokushima started a tradition of playing the ninth symphony on New Year's Even in memory of them. This tradition spread across the country and Beethoven's music is played in every town across the country to celebrate the end of the year. Beethoven's ninth has been the focal pion in historical and popular studies of not just prisoners in Japan but of the Japanese collective memory of the First World War.
>
> **<sub>- Murphy, Mahon. "Brucken, Beethoven und Baumkuchen: German and Austro-Hungarian Prisoners of War and the Japanese Home Front." *Other Fronts, other Wars? First World War Studies on the Eve of the Centennial* (2014).</sub>**

This established the tradition of performing Beethoven's Ninth to usher in the [Japanese New Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_New_Year).

Comment: My grandfather was a prisoner in that camp, playing violin in the orchestra. I'm in possession of quite a few historical documents and souvenirs relating to this that were among his personal papers and effects, including a list of many of his fellow prisoners, and even the violin he played there. His name was Ernest Baerwald, and he was one of the 63 Bando-ites to remain in Japan, until just before WWII broke out. He and his brother were also extremely active in helping many, many Eastern European Jews to escape Naziism through Japan, and then usually to Shanghai and Central America. Fascinati

Comment: @DavidBaerwald Your comment is the most interesting thing that I've found in the Internet in a lot of time.